# Reajustar pagina al generar pantalla emergente desde un form

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando una funcionalidad para cargar una imagen de un tercero a una base de datos, este proceso lo hago desde un `form` e incorporo un button para realizar la funcion de cargar imagen desde una vista.

el gran inconveniente es que al dar clic en el botón que conecta la otra vista y al desplegarse la pantalla emergente el contenido del `form` se amplia de manera considerable.

Esta es la linea y las propiedades que establezco para que sea posible generar la pantalla emergente

```
Response.Write("<Script Language=javascript>window.open('/Upload/Upload?nombre_campo=tercero.ruta_foto','Form','toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=yes,location=yes,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,fullscreen=no,width=400%,height=400%');</script>");
```

que debo cambiar para que esto no ocurra, de antemano gracias

incluyo las siguiente imagen para hacerme entender.

De este modo esta actualmente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que pretendo es que el formulario de atras quede del tamaño real, debe salirme de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que sucede es que el formulario incrementa el tamaño al momento de mostrarse la pantalla emergente.

Comment: mmm.. aca no hay nada de c#, el problema parece ser todo de javascript

Comment: ¿Ya has probado con css directo?

Comment: Puedes agregar imágenes de lo que mencionas o quieres lograr?

No me queda muy clara tu pregunta

Comment: ya edite la pregunta, para que veas mi inconveniente

Comment: Según lo que entiendo, lo que sucede es que los elementos de la forma crecen en tamaño al ser mostrada la página emergente, ¿Cierto? Si es así, ¿Podemos ver el código detrás del botón que levanta la ventana?

Comment: Exacto, eso es lo que sucede, es el que esta incorporado en la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esto

```
Response.Write("<Script Language=javascript>window.open('/Upload/Upload?nombre_campo=tercero.ruta_foto','Form','toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=yes,location=yes,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,fullscreen=no,width=400%,height=400%');</script>");
```

Por lo siguiente

```
Response.Write("<Script Language=javascript>window.open('/Upload/Upload?nombre_campo=tercero.ruta_foto','Form','toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=yes,location=yes,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,fullscreen=no,width=100%,height=100%');</script>");
```

El problema esta en los atributos **width y heigh**t de tu script

Comment: con estos atributos establezco el tamaño de la pantalla emergente, estableciendo un valor 100% indica que mi pantalla saldrá más reducida y el problema no se resolverá de esa manera